# Why (By Default) Foreign Key is Null ? . . and Can Foreign Key and Primary Key be the same Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, notnull

I have followed following steps:

1. Created Two Tables (No Constraint)
2. Alter Table#1 (Add Not Null and Primary Key Constraint)
3. Alter Table#2 (Add Foreign Key Constraint) . . And now Trying to Add Primary Key Constraint to Column which is Foreign Key for the
   Table#2

Got the Error like column can not be NULL.

Comment: Primary key can never be NULL... Since a primary key is unique..

Comment: You can't ad a primary key to a nullable column.

Answer (score 0):

It good practice for a foreign key to reference a primary key.  You are getting this error because a primary key can't be set on a nullable column.  Can you change the primary key to be an identity column ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, but what makes foreign key to be null by default? as with my question i need to set not null constraint for my foreign key also.

Comment: One of the columns referenced by the foreign key is defined as NOT NULL.  You need to change the column definition to NOT NULL.